# Pcap data to .ts file script

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap

I want to get the UDP stream of a pcap file, get the raw data and save to a .ts file. I now i can do that in Wireshark doing: `analyze->follow->UDP stream->show and save data as raw->save as->video.ts`.

How can i make a script in Python for doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could probably be done using `tshark` (wireshark-cli) (or dpkt or other tools)

But here's a solution with python's `scapy`.
(forgive my polluted namespace)

```
from scapy.all import *
import io

ts_pcap = sniff(offline='ts_sessions.pcap', filter='udp') # for example...

for five_tuple, session_packets in ts_pcap.sessions().items(): # going over each session
    session_buffer = io.BytesIO() # instead of writing each packet to disk, let's save each session's payload to memory. depending on the size of the streams this might be a bad idea.
    for packet in session_packets:
        session_buffer.write(bytes(packet['UDP'].payload)) # extracting udp payload from each packet, as bytes.
    exracted_ts_stream_name = five_tuple.replace(">", "_").replace(":","-") + ".ts"
    session_buffer.seek(0) # otherwise the pointer is at the end of the buffer
    with open(exracted_ts_stream_name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(session_buffer.read())
```